# SQL Add new timestamp if DATE is between (Kinda Static Date) Condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

So I need to add a timestamp in the result set if the record falls in this condition.

Example:

- Using todays date of "07-06-2011" as a comparison against a datetime, I need to add a timestamp to the result set if the record falls between the timestamps of MARCH 10th and APRIL 11th 2011
- Using a timestamp of "08-01-2011"as a comparison against a datetime, I need to add a timestamp to the result set if the record falls between APRIL 10th and MAY 11th 2011

and so on...

Having trouble with the syntax of the and how to calculate the specific dates, Any Ideas?

Example Data running for date: "07-06-2011"

- any date for the month of July should work but the March 10, 2011 and April 11, 2011 should stay the same until August. Then it should be the next two concurrent months

.

```
date_feild       new_date_feild
------------     --------------
"03-09-2011" 
"03-15-2011"     "07-06-2011"
"04-10-2011"     "07-06-2011"
"04-15-2011
```

Pseudo Query:

```
SELECT date_feild, CASE
    WHEN date_field BETWEEN (three months ago on the 10th) AND (two months ago on the 11th)
    THEN NOW() AS new_date_feild
END
FROM tbl_name
WHERE other_conditions
```

I guess I would like to know how to get these dates in this format:

- three months ago on the 10th
- two months ago on the 11th

UPDATE:

Well I have concocted this mess of a query, can anyone else help it along?

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
    TEXTCAT(
        TEXTCAT(
            TEXTCAT(
                date_part('YEARS', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 MONTHS'),
            '-'),
        date_part('MONTHS', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 MONTHS')),
    '-10'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS previous_date,
TO_DATE(
    TEXTCAT(
        TEXTCAT(
            TEXTCAT(
                date_part('YEARS', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 MONTHS'),
            '-'),
        date_part('MONTHS', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 MONTHS')),
    '-10'),'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' + INTERVAL '1 DAY' AS next_previous_date
```

Comment: Might want to explain your date format (we're not all the same) -- Is the last date August 1st, or January 8th?  I don't understand what you mean by "add a timestamp to the resultset -- example of expected output would help.

Comment: ok added some example data and Pseudo Query. I guess I'm looking to convert the datetimestamp into this format: three months ago on the 10th

Comment: Is there not a mistake in your description? Shouldn't it be 'between the *11th* of a month and the *10th* of the following month' (for both ranges)? The way it is now, it's not very clear what to do with the two dates of April 10, 2011 and April 11, 2011, because they belong to both ranges (unless the boundary dates are supposed to be excluded from their respective ranges).

Comment: Yeah I think I got the dates backwards in the example but the logic should be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is what I have but I'm not really happy with it:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
    TEXTCAT(
        TEXTCAT(
            TEXTCAT(
                date_part('YEARS', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 MONTHS'),
            '-'),
        date_part('MONTHS', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 MONTHS')),
    '-10'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS previous_date,
TO_DATE(
    TEXTCAT(
        TEXTCAT(
            TEXTCAT(
                date_part('YEARS', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 MONTHS'),
            '-'),
        date_part('MONTHS', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 MONTHS')),
    '-10'),'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' + INTERVAL '1 DAY' AS next_previous_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using DateTime, or just Date, instead.  Its easier for comparisons.  Had a similar problem myself, though much less involved.

Here's an easy link to different ways and efficiency: http://demiliani.com/blog/archive/2006/01/19/3384.aspx

It's also fairly easy to get the current date in java from this, though it took me forever to figure it out.  Here's how I did it:

```
//Get current DateTime
    java.util.Date javaDate = new java.util.Date();
    long javaTime = javaDate.getTime();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(javaTime);
    java.sql.Time sqlTime = new java.sql.Time(javaTime);
    String dateTime = sqlDate.toString() + " " + sqlTime.toString();
```

It's a bit weird, but sql seems to deal with this a lot better.

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not help in any way, why use Java when it can be done with SQL?

Comment: Ignore the java part then, just replace your Timestamp filed with a DateTime one.  SQL can handle comparisons with those.  another link: [linkfromsqlteam](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/timestamps-vs-datetime-data-types)

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for the efforts. I have updated my question with a Pseudo Query as to better explain what I'm trying to do

Comment: Looked here: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).  I think you could try converting the DateTime's to numeric (using +0), and then subtracting 3/2 months worth, think that's 300000000.  But then you would have to worry about different years.  I would just do this in another program, think sql might be too rigid.

Comment: Thanks for the persistent effort, the link you give it for MySQL and I'm running PostgreSQL. I did however add a query to get the dates I need and I can use this for the CASE condition. Just looking for a more efficient way. Thanks again for all you efforts